# How to get Bandwidth

Tags: android, splash-screen, bandwidth

I want to get the value of the bandwidth in my application.

At the launching of the app, I display a splash screen and data are loaded in AsyncTask. I use a Handler like this to display a progressBar :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(Activity_Splash_Screen.this, Activity_Main.class);
                i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("category", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) ListOfCategory);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

But, if the bandwidth is not optimal, the time to load data is more than the time of the variable SPLASH_TIME_OUT.

Therefore, i want to get the value of the bandwidth to adapt the value of my variable SPLASH_TIME_OUT.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: its not good to tie such action on processing time, assume a slower mobile is running the app or a faster mobile... why don't you show the progress `onPreExecute()` of the asyncTask, and hide it then open next activity `onPostExecute()` in case result is success or whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best way to show a splash screen. The splash screen must be shown until all mandatory data needed for your app is loaded. The approach with a static timeout doesn't work properly (or doesn't work at all on some devices). Why don't you try something like this?

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //Do your initial data loading here...

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }

        };
        asyncTask.execute(null, null);
    }
}
```